# Hash created by autovivification has extra keys

Tags: perl, hash, autovivification

This is what I have

```
my %count_words;

while (<DATA>){
    my $line= $_;
    chomp $line;
    my @words = split (/ /, "$line");
    foreach my $word(@words){
        $count_words{"$word"}++;
    }
}

foreach my $key (%count_words){
    print "\"$key\" occurs \"$count_words{$key}\" times\n";
}

__DATA__
we name is something
this is what it does
we food food food food
```

and this is the output i get

```
"it" occurs "1" times
"1" occurs "" times
"what" occurs "1" times
"1" occurs "" times
"name" occurs "1" times
"1" occurs "" times
"food" occurs "1" times
"1" occurs "" times
"does" occurs "1" times
"1" occurs "" times
"is" occurs "2" times
"2" occurs "" times
"we" occurs "2" times
"2" occurs "" times
"food" occurs "3" times
"3" occurs "" times
"something" occurs "1" times
"1" occurs "" times
"this" occurs "1" times
"1" occurs "" times
```

my question is why are there these additional keys created which are essentially the values of the previously created key->value pair.

this is what i would expect

```
"it" occurs "1" times
"what" occurs "1" times
"name" occurs "1" times
"food" occurs "1" times
"does" occurs "1" times
"is" occurs "2" times
"we" occurs "2" times
"food" occurs "3" times
"something" occurs "1" times
"this" occurs "1" times
```

Can someone please correct my obvious mistake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your error is in your foreach loop, you need the `keys` function:

```
foreach my $key ( keys %count_words){
    print "\"$key\" occurs \"$count_words{$key}\" times\n";
}
```

otherwise, your `foreach` is iterating through all keys AND values.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are not using

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

If you had, it would have given you a clue as to the error in your code

```
Use of uninitialized value $count_words{"1"}...
```

Or something to that effect.

The problem is, as Tim A has already pointed out, that you are using the hash in list context, which means that it expands into both keys and values. You should, like he suggested, use the `keys` function.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
foreach my $key (keys %count_words){
    print "\"$key\" occurs \"$count_words{$key}\" times\n";
}
```

The problem is that when you iterate through a hash, you alternately iterate through the keys **and** values.

Comment: `print qq("$key occurs "$count_words{$key}" times"\n);`